# Mongo javascript validation

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to create mongo users using javascript as part of an installation script.

I would like to know how to validate the return statement of the previous command before proceeding with the next.

For example in the following script,

```
var db = db.getSiblingDB("admin");
var status = db.createUser({user: "root",
  pwd: "root",
  roles: [
    { role: "root", db: "admin" }
  ]
});
```

I need to verify if `db.createUser` succeeded before running further commands.

Is it possible? When I tried to print `status`, console threw `undefined type` error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to verify if db.createUser succeeded before running further commands.

By default, you can *rely* that this particular command succeeded, if you didn't get any error. If it can't add a user (because user with this name already exists), an error will be raised. Something like this:

```
2017-03-20T19:17:42.097+0300 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't add user: User "root@admin" already exists :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.createUser@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1267:15
@(shell):1:14
```

If you want to be extra sure, look for your newly added user in the output of `db.getUsers()`.

Comment: Is there a way to validate it from within javascript? Can this mongo level error log be caught in the js?

Comment: @Nataraj Have you tried? It should propagate to client side, yes